# jquery autocomplete not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

Please help; the following code does not execute an autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.chapter a[href*="wikipedia"]').attr({
        rel: 'external',
        title: function () {
            return 'Learn more about ' + $(this).text()
            + ' at Wikipedia.';
        },
        id: function (index, oldValue) {
            return 'wikilink-' + index;
        }
    });

    $('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter('div.chapter p');
    $('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');

    $('#shakeButton').button({
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-pause' }
    });

    $('#shakeButton').click(function () {

        $('#shakeButton').effect('shake', {
            distance: 5,
            duration: 100
        });


    });

    $('#nameText').autocomplete({
        source: GetNames()
        //,minLength: 3
    });
});


function GetNames() {

    var availableTags = [];

    var params = {
        term: $('#nameText').val()
    };

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Autocomplete",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params)
    });

    request.done(function (data) {
       availableTags = data
       return availableTags;
    });


    //var availableTags = [
    //  "ActionScript",
    //  "AppleScript",
    //  "Asp",
    //  "BASIC",
    //  "C",
    //  "C++",
    //  "Clojure",
    //  "COBOL",
    //  "ColdFusion",
    //  "Erlang",
    //  "Fortran",
    //  "Groovy",
    //  "Haskell",
    //  "Java",
    //  "JavaScript",
    //  "Lisp",
    //  "Perl",
    //  "PHP",
    //  "Python",
    //  "Ruby",
    //  "Scala",
    //  "Scheme"
    //];
    //return availableTags;

}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps console.log(data) to confirm that you are returning valid JSON?!

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetNames()` doesn't return anything.

```
function GetNames() {

    // The function within request.done will be called when the request
    // is finished
    request.done(function (data) {
       availableTags = data
       return availableTags;
    });

    // But code-execution will go immediately to this position and exit
    // the function GetNames() without a return-value

}
```

The manual of JQuery-UI has two examples how to fetch data with JSON: [Remote](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and [Remote JSONP](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) (click view source).

```
$( "#nameText" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/Home/Autocomplete",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described how you expect your code to work, so I'm only guessing here:

Your function `GetNames()` should make and ajax request to `/Home/Autocomplete` and return available tags when it gets the result.

Your problem is:

```
function GetNames() {
    // ...
    request.done(function (data) {
        availableTags = data
        return availableTags; // you're returning availableTags here
    });
    // You're expecting to get availableTags returned here
    // but nothing (undefined) is returned
}
```

This can't be done in a typical function return way, because that's how AJAX works (**Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML)

A possible solution:

```
$('#nameText').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Autocomplete",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    // ...
});
```

This example is copied from [Autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). So maybe next time, you should go check the docs for reference before asking here on SO, you'll probably get your answer quicker. This applies for any library/framework.